# How to create well-aligned, clean structure to define a function (mathematics)?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath, diagrams, commutative-diagrams

I am new to Latex. I am aiming to define a function appropriately using latex, that is to first define the sets, e.g. $f:X \to Y$ and then how the elements map into the image, i.e. $x \to f(x)$. I would like both rows to align well. Below is the code and problem I encountered:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
X \colon T &\rightarrow {}&& \mathcal{D} \\
           t&\mapsto \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{\substack{i = 0,...,m}}(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\cdot(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n}))\\
           \end{alignat*}
```

[image]

I want the "D" to be just in line with the start of the limit in the "mapsto" row. Could anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: Welcome! Use `align` (not `alginat`). `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
X \colon T &\rightarrow \mathcal{D} \\
     t&\mapsto \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}
      \sum_{\substack{i =0,\dots,m}}
   (f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\cdot(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n}))
\end{align*}
\end{document}`

Comment: (Not tested.)  @Schrödinger'scat has given a good suggestion.  `align` is the way to go.  I'm just going to verbally suggest adjustments.  The `&&` you used is what is shifting the  `\mathcal{D}` way off to the right, so get rid of them.  But since there is a limit on `\lim`, the "l" may be a bit to the right of the "D".  Rather than trying to shift the `\lim` expression, if it's needed add a small space before the "D".  `\,` should be more than enough; if it's *too* much, then `\mspace{2mu}` should work.  (`mu` is a "math" unit, and a thin space = `3mu`.)

Comment: To explain what happened: the aligning environments line everything up on the `&` symbols.  Since the first row has more `&` than the second, the extra `&` come after everything in the second row, and then the `\mathcal{D}` comes after that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want the `\mathcal{D}` to be just in line with the start of the limit in the `\mapsto` row.

I would use a top-aligned `aligned` (pun intended...) environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for "\smashoperator" macro
\begin{document}
\[
X \colon \begin{aligned}[t]
          &T\rightarrow \mathcal{D} \\
          &t\mapsto \lim_{n \to \infty}
             \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{i = 0,\dots,m}}
             (f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n}))\cdot
             (f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n}))
         \end{aligned}          
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's a solution that implements @barbarabeeton's suggestion that the `\rightarrow` and `\mapsto` symbols should be aligned as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
X \colon \begin{array}[t]{ r >{{}}c<{{}} >{\displaystyle}l }
          T &\rightarrow &\mathcal{D} \\[0.5ex]
          t & \mapsto    & 
             \smashoperator[l]{\lim_{n \to \infty}}
             \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{i = 0,\dots,m}}
             \bigl(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\bigr)
             \bigl(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\bigr)
         \end{array}          
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, but really, the arrows should also be aligned.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - That's not what the OP wrote (but I agree with you anyway!).

Comment: Not what s/he wrote, but what it looks like in the visual.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Please see the addendum I just posted, with a solution that follows your guidelines.

Comment: Yes.  That does it.

Answer (score 7):

Using Vincent's idea of an `array`, but with some more tricks to keep barbara beeton happy:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,calc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{
  @{}
  r
  @{}
  c
  @{}
  >{\displaystyle{}}l
  @{}
}
X \colon{} & T & \to \mathop{\mathmakebox[\widthof{$\lim$}][l]{\mathcal{D}}}_{\hphantom{n\to\infty}} \\[1ex]
           & t & \mapsto 
               \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=0,\dots,m} \mspace{-9mu}
                  \bigl(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\bigr)\cdot\bigl(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\bigr)
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I'd simply do

```latex
We can define the map $X\colon T\to\mathcal{D}$ by
\begin{equation*}
X(t)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=0,\dots,m} \mspace{-9mu}
      \bigl(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\bigr)\cdot\bigl(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\bigr)
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the last advice!

Answer (score 4):

After seeing the other answers... I really would like to reiterate [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533142/how-to-create-well-aligned-clean-structure-to-define-a-function-mathematics?noredirect=1#comment1348250_533142) and use `align` here, with all the explanations being contained in [barbara's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533142/how-to-create-well-aligned-clean-structure-to-define-a-function-mathematics?noredirect=1#comment1348253_533142) (sorry, Mico ;-).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
X \colon T &\rightarrow \mathcal{D} \\
           t&\mapsto \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}
            \sum_{\substack{i =0,\dots,m}}
            (f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\cdot(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n}))
\end{align*}

\emph{Maybe} one could use \verb|\mathclap| to align the $\mathcal{D}$ with
$\lim$ (but I am not coninced).
\begin{align*}
X \colon T &\rightarrow \mathcal{D} \\
           t&\mapsto \lim\limits_{\mathclap{n \to \infty}}\;
            \sum_{\substack{i =0,\dots,m}}
            (f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\cdot(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n}))
\end{align*}
Or, in the spirit of barbara beeton's comment.
\begin{align*}
X \colon T &\rightarrow\setbox0\hbox{$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}$}%
\setbox1\hbox{$\lim$}%
\hspace{\the\dimexpr0.5\wd0-0.5\wd1}\mathcal{D} \\
           t&\mapsto \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\;
            \sum_{\substack{i =0,\dots,m}}
            (f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\cdot(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n}))
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good.  Thanks.  (I like the last example best; the gap after the "T" balances the space before the "D", even though that's largely a consequence of shape.  To my eyes, the lower limit in the second example looks a bit squeezed next to the arrow.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree, which is why I wrote that I am not convinced about that one. Even the simpleminded `align` looks good IMHO,

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the `array` environment for these definitions, since the syntax is rather visual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{r@{\ }c@{\ }c@{\ }l}
X \colon & T & \to     & \mathcal{D} \\
         & t & \mapsto & \displaystyle \smashoperator[l]{\lim_{n \to \infty}} \sum_{i=0,...,m} \bigl( f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n})\cdot(f(t_{i,n})-f(t_{i-1,n}) \bigr)
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This way everything is aligned correctly. If the `\lim_{n\to\infty}` appears to be too close to the `\mapsto` symbol, some spacing could be added (for example with `\,`) before both the `\mathcal{D}` and the `\lim_{n\to\infty}` commands. Of course if this spacing is added but not on both lines, the alignment will be lost.

Comment: This is technically correct, but the "D" isn't lined up with "lim",  See my comment on the question.

Comment: To line up the `\mathcal{D}` and `lim` particles, you could load the `mathtools` package and replace `\lim_{n \to \infty}` with `\smashoperator[l]{\lim_{n \to \infty}}`.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions! I corrected the alignment of the ``\mathcal{D}`` and the ``\lim`` symbols.